# how to use laravel collective package v5.4 in laravel v5.7

Tags: laravel, package

I am using laravel 5.7. I want to use laravel collective package. But latest updated laravel collective package is 5.4. When I am trying to install from composer it shows error :

> ' [UnexpectedValueException]   Could not parse version constraint
>   :5.7: Invalid version string ":5.7"'

Please suggest now how can I use collective package in laravel 5.7?

Comment: what you try for install package

Comment: At first I tried : composer require "laravelcollective/html":"^5.4.0"

Then I tried : composer require "laravelcollective/html":"^5.7"

In both case i have failed

Comment: try `composer require laravelcollective/html`

Comment: Thanks a lot... Seems now it is working... :)

Comment: Happy to help :) @muhammad